# Converting bit position to mask value

Tags: c, embedded

I want to calculate the value of the mask dynamically based on bit position.

For Example: The mask value for the 17th bit in a 32-bit value is 0x00020000 and that of the 18th bit is 0x00040000. So if I know the bit positions like 17, 18 etc., how can this be converted dynamically to mask values in C? Of course left shifting is one method (`1<<17` or `1<<18`). But I am thinking left shifting may consume too many instructions! Or is left shifting itself the best and efficient method?

Comment: Normally it's a single instruction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, it won't consume too many instructions. What you are doing may be fine in one operation. Here is an answer that explains this on SO: [Which is faster:  x<<1  or  x<<10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234120/which-is-faster-x1-or-x10) Basically there is no difference in speed.

Please see this answer on SO too for implementations:  [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c)

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. But statement like IO0CLR=(1<<18) may alter the other bits of IO0CLR also right? So I need to do something like IO0CLR|=(1<<18). Few programs in Eval boards make use of statements IO0CLR=(1<<18) since they are executing very small example programs independently and not bothered about other bits I guess.

Comment: In addition to the linked answer about the barrel shifter, note that most embedded targets (even most ARM cortex M implementations that have a barrel shifter) include bit addressing functionality and any decent compiler will optimise a single bit manipulation to use them.

Answer (score 2):

In most architectures support a single atomic instruction for logical-shift-left.  For example:

- MIPS:  SSL
- ARM: LSL
- x86: SHL
- AVR: LSL

PIC microcontrollers are however a more complex story. Different versions of PIC have different instruction sets, and not all include a logical-shift-left.  Low-end (prior to PIC24/sdPIC) PIC instruction sets are not particularly suited to C code generation in any case since they lack direct support for many apparently insignificant C operations.

You should check your target's instruction set and the actual assembler/machine code generated by your compiler - most compilers have support for outputting assembler listings, or you can disassemble the output in your debugger or simulator, or a standalone disassembler.

In the unlikely absence of an logical-shift-left or a compiler optimisation that makes best use of the existing instruction set, you could (at no insignificant memory cost) use a look-up table to at least optimise for time, but in most cases a part with no logical-shift-left is likely to also have very small memory resources, so it is perhaps an impractical solution.

Comment: Also LSL on all Freescale MCUs (very similar assembler to AVR/Atmel), SLDI on PowerPC. _"On every microcontroller but PIC..."_ sounds like a familiar phrase :)