# How to multiply a register by 37 using only 2 consecutive leal instructions in x86?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, multiplication, strength-reduction

Say %edi contains x and I want to end up with 37*x using only 2 consecutive leal instructions, how would I go about this?

For example to get 45x you would do

```
leal (%edi, %edi, 8), %edi   
leal (%edi, %edi, 4), %eax (to be returned)
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out what numbers to put in place of the 8 and 4 so that the result (%eax) will be 37x

Comment: Did you try asking a compiler?  https://godbolt.org/g/nMbujJ.  Hint: you have to change more than the scale factors.  The 2nd LEA uses the original input + the first LEA result.

Comment: Also, given your choice of registers, this look like you're using 64-bit code for the System V ABI.  There's no benefit to using an address-size override prefix to get 32-bit addressing modes in 64-bit mode.  It's always safe to let `lea` truncate a 64-bit addressing mode to 32-bit.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377711/which-2s-complement-integer-operations-can-be-used-without-zeroing-high-bits-in

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[At `-O3`, gcc will emit (Godbolt compiler explorer)](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'int+mul37(int+a)+%7B+return+a*37%3B+%7D%0A%0A%23define+MUL(x)+int+mul%23%23x+(int+a)+%7B+return+a*x%3B+%7D%0AMUL(45)%0A%0AMUL(21)++//+same+pattern+as+*37+for+both+gcc+and+clang%0A%0AMUL(20)%0AMUL(19)++//+gcc+uses+2+lea,+clang+uses+lea%2Bshl%2Bsub%0AMUL(18)%0AMUL(17)%0AMUL(16)%0AMUL(15)%0A%0A//+-mtune%3Dsilvermont+should+probably+favour+fewer+insns%0A//+since+it+mostly+bottlenecks+on+decode+and+has+3c+imul%0A%0AMUL(34)+//+gcc+and+clang+both+use+imul%0A//+except+with+-m32+-mtune%3Dpentium+or+pentium3+pentium4%0A//+or+(64-bit)+-mtune%3Dnocona+(64-bit+Prescott+P4)%0A%0A//+ICC+uses+mov/shl/lea+for+34+%3D+32%2B2%0A//+so+it!'s+cheaper+than+what+clang+does+for+19%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:36.39118870986115,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g72,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),libs:!(),options:'-xc+-Wall+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),header:(),k:31.897129859778083,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang500,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),libs:!(),options:'-xc+-Wall+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+5.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)',t:'0')),header:(),k:31.711681430360763,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4):

```
int mul37(int a)  { return a*37; }

    leal    (%rdi,%rdi,8), %eax      # eax = a * 9
    leal    (%rdi,%rax,4), %eax      # eax = a + 4*(a*9)
    ret
```

That's using `37 = 9*4 + 1`, **not destroying the original `a` value with the first `lea` so it can use both in the 2nd.**

You're in good company in not spotting this one, though: recent clang (3.8 and newer) will normally use 2 `lea` instructions instead of an `imul` (e.g. for `*15`), but it misses this one and uses:

```
    imull   $37, %edi, %eax
    ret
```

It does do `*21` with the same pattern as gcc uses, as `5*4 + 1`.  (clang3.6 and earlier always used `imul` unless there was a single-instruction alternative `shl` or `lea`)

ICC and MSVC also use imul, but they don't seem to like using 2 `lea` instructions, so the `imul` is "on purpose" there.

See the godbolt link for a variety of multipliers with gcc7.2 vs. clang5.0.  It's interesting to try `gcc -m32 -mtune=pentium` or even `pentium3` to see how many more instructions gcc was wiling to use back then.  Although P2/P3 has 4-cycle latency for `imul r, r, i`, so that's kinda crazy.  Pentium has 9 cycle `imul` and no OOO to hide the latency, so it makes sense to try hard to avoid it.

`mtune=silvermont` should probably only be willing to replace 32-bit `imul` with a single instruction, because it has 3-cycle latency / 1c throughput multiply, but decode is often the bottleneck (according to Agner Fog, http://agner.org/optimize/).  You could even consider `imul $64, %edi, %eax` (or other powers of 2) instead of `mov`/`shl`, because imul-immediate is a copy-and-multiply.

---

Ironically, `gcc` misses the `* 45` case, and uses `imul`, while clang uses 2 `lea`s.  Guess it's time to file some missed-optimization bug reports.  *If* 2 LEAs are better than 1 IMUL, they should be used wherever possible.

Older clang (3.7 and older) uses `imul` unless a single `lea` will do the trick.  I haven't looked up the changelog to see if they did benchmarks to decide to favour latency over throughput.

---

Related: [Using LEA on values that aren't addresses / pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597055/using-lea-on-values-that-arent-addresses-pointers/46597375#46597375) canonical answer about why LEA uses memory-operand syntax and machine encoding, even though it's a shift+add instruction (and runs on an ALU, not AGU, in most modern microarchitectures.)

Comment: "clang will normally use 2 lea instructions instead of an imul" I've made the opposite observation. From what I've seen, Clang tends to prefer emitting a single `IMUL` over any alternative sequence of instructions. I thought about reporting it as an optimization defect a while back, actually, but then I decided it just doesn't matter. The performance impact is virtually immeasurable. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray: that changed in clang3.7 or something.  I guess they decided to favour latency over throughput.  But yes, older clang did prefer `imul` unless it could use a single `lea`.