# Understanding and analyzing assembly code

Tags: assembly, x86

can anyone help me understand this assembly code? I'm totally new to the assembly language and I just can't figure it out...
The following assembly code should produce this function:

> func(int a)
>   { return a * 34 }

The comments // are my thoughts what it should mean, please correct me if I'm wrong

```
//esp = stack-pointer, ebp = callee saved, eax = return value

pushl %ebp                   // a is pushed on stack
movl %esp,%ebp               // a = stackpointer
movl 8(%ebp),%eax            // eax = M(8 + a).But what is in M(8 + a)?
sall $4,%eax                 // eax << 4
addl 8(%ebp),%eax            // eax = M(8 + a)
addl %eax,%eax               // eax = eax + eax
movl %ebp,%esp               // eax = t
popl %ebp                    // pop a from stack
ret
```

Could someone please explain me how to figure this out? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The first two lines have nothing to do with `a`. They just set up the stack frame. `8(%ebp)` is `a`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
pushl %ebp                   // a is pushed on stack
movl %esp,%ebp               // a = stackpointer
```

As noted in a comment, `ebp` has nothing to do with `a`. `ebp` is the stack base pointer -- this code saves the old value of `ebp` to the stack, then saves the stack pointer in `ebp`.

```
movl 8(%ebp),%eax            // eax = M(8 + a).But what is in M(8 + a)?
```

Correct. What's on the stack is the input value of `eax`.

```
sall $4,%eax                 // eax << 4
```

Correct. (And the result is assigned back to `eax`.)

```
addl 8(%ebp),%eax            // eax = M(8 + a)
```

No, you've misunderstood this. This adds the value on the stack at `8(ebp)` -- which is the original value of `a` -- to `eax`. The addition is applied to the values, not memory addresses.

```
addl %eax,%eax               // eax = eax + eax
```

Correct. The value of `eax` is not modified beyond here, so this is the return value of the function.

```
movl %ebp,%esp               // eax = t
popl %ebp                    // pop a from stack
ret
```

This code reverses the effects of the first two instructions. It's a standard cleanup sequence, and has nothing to do with `a`.

The important parts of this function can be glossed as:

```
a1 = a << 4;   // = a * 16
a2 = a1 + a;   // = a * 17
a3 = a2 + a2;  // = a * 34
return a3;
```

Comment: *"You've got this backwards. This moves eax (which carries the original value of a) to the stack."* no, it's AT&T syntax, so you have got it backward... it loads value from stack memory into `eax`, i.e. truly loads `a` into `eax`. ... the `a` is sent on stack in the OP's calling convention, and `eax` can contain pretty much anything upon entry.

Comment: @Ped7g Ah, you're right -- corrected my post. I was thinking of x86-64 calling conventions.

Answer (score 2):

This is craptastic un-optimized code because you compiled with `-O0` (compile fast, skip most optimization passes).  The legacy stack-frame setup / cleanup is just noise.  The arg is on the stack right above the return address, i.e. at `4(%esp)` on function entry.  (See also [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output))

**It's surprising to see a compiler use 3 instructions to multiply by shifting and adding, instead of an `imull  $34, 4(%esp), %eax` / `ret`**, unless tuning for old CPUs.  2 instructions is the cutoff for modern gcc and clang with their default tuning.  See for example [How to multiply a register by 37 using only 2 consecutive leal instructions in x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46480579/how-to-multiply-a-register-by-37-using-only-2-consecutive-leal-instructions-in-x)

But this *can* be done with 2 instructions using LEA (not counting `mov` to copy a register); the code is bloated because you compiled without optimization.  (Or you tuned for an old CPU where there's maybe some reason to avoid LEA.)

I think you must have used gcc for this; disabling optimization with other compilers always just uses `imul` to multiply by a non-power-of-2.  But I can't find a gcc version + options on the Godbolt compiler explorer that gives exactly your code.  I didn't try every possible combination.  MSVC 19.10 `-O2` uses the same algorithm as your code, including loading `a` twice.

Compiling with gcc5.5 (which is the newest gcc that doesn't just use `imul`, even at `-O0`), we get something like your code, but not exactly.  (Same operations in a different order, and not loading `a` from memory twice).

```
# gcc5.5 -m32 -xc -O0 -fverbose-asm -Wall
func:
    pushl   %ebp  #
    movl    %esp, %ebp      #,            # make a stack frame

    movl    8(%ebp), %eax   # a, tmp89    # load a from the stack, first arg is at EBP+8

    addl    %eax, %eax      # tmp91          # a*2
    movl    %eax, %edx      # tmp90, tmp92
    sall    $4, %edx        #, tmp92         # a*2 << 4 = a*32
    addl    %edx, %eax      # tmp92, D.1807  # a*2 + a*32

    popl    %ebp    #                     # clean up the stack frame
    ret
```

Compiling **with optimization** with the same older GCC version on **[the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5HhYEA1ADMRLZBFkKmASnkcA7D3nFMBMS3lN5AKnkBmACwdbh/QBEOABgCCUrY2kArFKkLNIewajSAML8/PLCYhK6XLa0wQRhvn4A1iBcegB0XABsXLQAHOXFAQCcXPZ69uUB/lL2wQC2dB4eIZmkkVLBgiC9GVLhfnCwMIgoqB0ADngMmGQUEGhLK2sgwOVcpIorBGsjEABG/ReyTMQAntJppFsdmHIA8iwMjxPBWB1WMBVv18MZkAQ8AA3TAjP6kTAAD0wyBEpyewQ0mAYGMYeAuxDu9yiGEkUmeBGIeC65N8jCBKFivDxFxGkD8qEWkNQLDhAFoPrZ5HyOqYWJgnK5Fu9ISIOkKRbYuMLEchhYoYcQLqhBJg%2BUxBB1hQB1JgMBjDUTiSS0Pw4qRBPrwwaIqp84r2eTAZBq8pFeQQXCEEjJVKkeQk7arYih20Rpk8dKZLR%2BBCYJhYYiUHIgWzFArFA41Dz2Go1PS0LjlexcFr29qkLoBXqhZ3SYajUjjSakaZzLbLaPkSgDnZZ4ABZtHE5nShXeE3FhE3GvGVfH6gzCAtgg%2BFglGQmFw8II5Go9G08hybG4hj4wkPElYXGU6kYu0Mzi8fgstkQDlcngPL8vKyp8qqwqCuqmrarq%2BqGiaZoWkIVoSHQdqBMErYni6boel6PryAEBQBAGQZEDG3BhhGCyDmsoZcDoMTfrwSZ/CmpBphmuz/q0DZNi2/SDB2YzJjmeYFkWJZlhWVY1nW0i2FhQntl2ya9rMfYQEgo5Dhsum7MgzBsHoPTTgwpzEOc84nouy6XqunzfL8J4AkCu6uXg4KHrC/RIiiaJks8WL2s8d4EkST5BekVI0mkH5sIyLECOFf4AdyvLSIqYEQQKCoamssF6gaRp8qa5ryMKgLiAgkoIAaADu2LIQk1roa0jrYRE0iusU7qekZQLyIUHgFB4ZH4BRsbhpGdGUSkthMQmbGTOJ%2BY1KUHjlg4pkBPYtgKW0nQgFOXUDKpIyiexGnwNp8xRmsw6bLRY4oAwtA1AA%2BlwHi0AEn0iLYn1KuZlnWdctwPCuCxvE5G57lu7lkp53nQr58L%2Bee0VXqcoXBOFD7EqSL6xe%2B9KJV%2BfDMql8DpUBmVSAKXCWokNoYQ6yltlIvXyB0ghQmqUIfWNAbGgAkgActgOiBpNIZUfQNEPfNDhLclK1ZJx6aZtmfHHadKlDEInbdpruQSR4e3FsUDh5vU9D2kpTo4appscfazPO91Rtu34mqCPTID2EAA%3D%3D%3D)**: `gcc5.5 -m32 -O3 -fverbose-asm`, we get:

```
# gcc5.5 -m32 -O3.   Also clang7.0 -m32 -O3 emits the same code
func:
    movl    4(%esp), %eax   # a, a          # load a from the stack
    movl    %eax, %edx      # a, tmp93      # copy it to edx
    sall    $5, %edx        #, tmp93        # edx = a<<5 = a*32
    leal    (%edx,%eax,2), %eax             # eax = edx + eax*2 = a*32 + a*2 = a*34
    ret              # with a*34 in EAX, the return-value reg in this calling convention
```

**With gcc 6.x or newer, we get this efficient asm**: `imul`-immediate with a memory source decodes to only a single micro-fused uop on modern Intel CPUs, and integer multiply only has 3 cycle latency on Intel since Core2 and AMD since Ryzen.  (https://agner.org/optimize/).

```
# gcc6/7/8 -m32 -O3     default tuning
func:
    imull   $34, 4(%esp), %eax    #, a, tmp89
    ret
```

**But with `-mtune=pentium3`, we strangely don't get an LEA**.  This looks like a missed optimization.  LEA has 1-cycle latency on Pentium 3 / Pentium-M.

```
# gcc8.2 -O3 -mtune=pentium3 -m32 -xc -fverbose-asm -Wall
func:
    movl    4(%esp), %edx   # a, a
    movl    %edx, %eax      # a, tmp91
    sall    $4, %eax        #, tmp91     # a*16
    addl    %edx, %eax      # a, tmp92   # a*16 + a = a*17
    addl    %eax, %eax      # tmp93      # a*16 * 2 = a*34
    ret
```

This is the same as your code, but uses a reg-reg `mov` instead of reloading from the stack to add `a` to the shift result.