# Finding an efficient shift/add/LEA instruction sequence to multiply by a given constant (avoiding MUL/IMUL)

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, x86-64, bit-shift, micro-optimization

I'm trying to write a C program mult.c that has a main function that receives 1 int argument (parsed with `atoi(argv[1])`), that is some constant `k` we want to multiply by.

**This program will generate an assembly file `mult.s` that implements**

```
int mult(int x) {
   return x * k;
}
```

for that constant `k`.  (This is a followup to [Efficient Assembly multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59227227/efficient-assembly-multiplication))

For example: if main() in mult.c gets 14 as argument it may generate (though it is not minimal as later emphasized):

```
.section .text
.globl mult
mult:              # by 14
    movl %edi,%eax         # arg passed in EDI
    shl $3,%eax
    movl %edi,%ecx
    shl $2,%ecx
    addl %ecx,%eax
    movl %edi,%ecx
    shl $1,%ecx
    addl %ecx,%eax
    ret
```

The assembly function recieves its argument in the %rdi register and returns its result in the %rax register.

I need to consider these following rules:

0) The assembly program should be minimal in terms of lines of code. (Dynamic instruction count).  I'll worry about critical path latency later.

1. if k is 0,1,-1 no need to multiply (obviously) - `xor %eax,%eax`, `mov %edi, %eax`, or `neg`
2. if k is 3,5,9 I then need to replace the multiplication command in LEA.
3. if k is 3*2^n, 5*2^n, 9*2^n then I need to replace the multiplication command in LEA and shifting.
4. all other cases suppose to work also of course.

I'm having trouble with cases 3 and 4.

3. how can I identify a number is of this structure in my c program?
4. what do I do with negative numbers?

And a general cases that relates to both, Am I just suppose to mask, add and shift my constant 32 times (the number of bits in an integer)? 
Is there anything better?

Comment: x86 doesn't have a MULT instruction?  Are you thinking of [IMUL](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/imul), or maybe widening MUL?  Maybe you're thinking of MIPS's MULT mnemonic.

Comment: It does but the whole point of this exercise is to avoid using it so we get a feel of what happens behind the scenes...

Comment: Yes, but if you only need to avoid an instruction that doesn't exist, the question would be trivial :P  The answer would be to use `imul` because it's not called `mult`.  Anyway, fixed your title for you along with the formatting mess that was the rest of your question.  (Also added some fixes, have a look at the diff.  e.g. `main` gets string args in argv, not `int`.)

Comment: re: negative numbers: you can just treat `k` as unsigned.  For 2's complement, the only difference between signed and unsigned multiplication is in the high 32 bits of a full 32x32 => 64-bit multiply.  (e.g. on x86, `mul` and `imul` give the same EAX, potentially different EDX.  This is why only `imul` has new efficient versions like `imul r, r/m32`)

Comment: re: the general case: in a real compiler you *would* just fall back to `imul eax, edi, 12345` for cases with a lot of set bits, where it would take more than some threshold of shift / add / sub instructions.  Also, IIRC, my answer on [Efficient Assembly multiplication](//stackoverflow.com/q/59227227) pointed out a specific technique for stripping off an arbitrary power of 2 so you can check what's left.  `shiftcount = __builtin_ctz` then right shift by that, removing all the leading zeros.  So you could do that for case 3.

Comment: Note that there aren't many numbers of the form for case 3.  I would build a look up table for all numbers of the form and simply check if it's in there.

Comment: How is this question different to the question you say it is a follow-up to? Seems to me that @PeterCordes already addressed the algorithm for determining if a multiplier has exactly two bits set, as well as figuring out the power-of-two factor, in his [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59229397/1566221).

Comment: @rici: I added the fact that it was a followup while tidying up this question, the OP neglected to mention it at all.  I think this question is looking for more detailed help with implementation details, and as such is more like a beginner / homework question where we need the OP to make an attempt in actual code that might be buggy or have one *small* missing piece.  (I was surprised this got asked; I thought I already pretty much covered this in sufficient detail to implement, like you said.)

Comment: Hmm, correct me if I'm wrong but this reminds of a rather important task of finding an optimal sequence for a "modular exponentiation using variable size sliding windows technique". As far as I can recall (although it's been a while) the solution of this task is not trivial, so - good luck with that. ))  Important bit related to the question, though - does your *k* has any limits? Min, max?