# 4-argument Lea with the base left out

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, att

I can't for the love of me figure this one out.
I'd assume the instruction
`lea 0x0(,%rcx,4),%esi`

to mean "set %esi to the result of multiplication of %rcx by 4".
But that's not it. So what does it mean? It's odd in the first place that
the offset is 0x0 and that mul isn't used instead...

EDIT:
I think something is implicitly used as a base. But I don't know what.

Comment: 0 is used as the base. It is 0+[0+rcx*4] . What makes you think otherwise. What value do you get for ESI? What was the value of RCX before the instruction executed?

Comment: “set %esi to the result of multiplication of %rcx by 4” – this is exactly what this instruction does.  Could it perhaps be subject to a relocation not filled in yet?

Comment: See my answer :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was my mistake. I overlooked the fact the destination is marked as 32-bit.
What this means is if the result of the multiplication is higher than that, it will get cut off.

So if you have some long value such as 2400923063, 2400923063*4=0x23c6cb6dc, but then the last half-byte will get cut off, and you will get 0x3c6cb6dc as the result (1013757660).

Comment: Yup, the net result is just a simple left-shift by 2.  The reason for using `lea` instead of `shl` is to non-destructively put the result in another register instead of modifying ECX.  (In your question, you say "odd that mul isn't used instead", but that would be insane for a power of 2, unless you're optimizing for code-size over speed, then yes `imul $4, %ecx, %esi` might be even more compact than `mov` + `shl`.  [Using LEA on values that aren't addresses / pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46597375) / [Efficient Assembly multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59227227)