# Nested Arrays in Assembly, reach desired index

Tags: c, assembly, multidimensional-array, x86-64, reverse-engineering

This is about reaching desired index in nested arrays in Assembly language. Let me start.

- First of all, I know that for a given array "A", you can reach A[i][j] by; *A + i * (C * K) + j * K* given that C is the element number in an array. K is the byte that type of the elements in A requires.

So it makes sense. For example, you want to reach int A[3][4] in A[5][5], you have to get through 3 arrays in A. Each of them consists 4 elements that costs 4 bytes per element. Therefore;
*A + 3 ( 4 * 5 ) + 4 * 4*. First, you get through 12 elements which you should walk on the addresses by 48 bytes. Then, you are at the beginning of the desired row. Then you skip 4 elements (16 bytes) and desired column, in other words 5th element in that row.

However, we had an example in class and I totally do not understand what is going on. I can not mail teacher since I know that will not result in any. So please help me to understand this.

```
#define M ??
#define N ??
long P[M][N];
long Q[N][M];
long sum_elem(long i, long j)
{
return P[i][j] + Q[j][i];
}
```

```
# long sum_elem(long i, long j)
# in %rdi, j in %rsi
1 sum_element:
2 leaq 0(,%rdi,8), %rdx          # Computing 8*i and copy it onto %rdx.
3 subq %rdi, %rdx                # 8*i - i = 7*i
4 addq %rsi, %rdx                # 7*i + j 
5 leaq (%rsi,%rsi,4), %rax       # 4*j + j = 5*j
6 addq %rax, %rdi                # 5*j + i 
7 movq Q(,%rdi,8), %rax          # Retrieve [Q + 8*(5*j + i)]. 
8 add P(,%rdx,8), %rax           # Retrieve [P + 8*(7*i + j)] and add it to %rax.
9 ret
```

As you can guess, we are expected to answer for M and N values. It is stated that M = 5 and N = 7 however, if we investigated one of the above, i.e. [P + 8*(7*i + j)], then 8 stands for K value in our very beginning definition. 7 stands for C, which is the number of elements that an array in A contains. Therefore, I believe that it should be M = 7 and N = 5 which is the reverse of the answer.

Am I correct and it is just an typo or do I miss something?

Thank you all.

EDIT: I had a typo while writing, thanks to the answer it is corrected.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, you want to reach int A[3][4] in A[5][5], you have to get through 3 arrays in A. Each of them consists 4 elements that costs 4 bytes per element.

Not quite. Each of them consists of 5 elements, because it's declared as A[5][5].

3 and 4 are indices, 5 and 5 are sizes. When calculating the offset, you need to multiply the *index* in the outer array by the *size* of the inner one. Does that make sense?

EDIT: The formula A + `3 ( 4 * 4 ) + 4 * 4` is wrong. Should be A + `3 ( 5 * 4 ) + 4 * 4` because the inner array size is 5. That gives you `A+76`.

For a 5x5 array, the memory goes:

```
 0: A[0][0] <-the 0th subarray starts at A
 4: A[0][1]
 8: A[0][2]
12: A[0][3]
16: A[0][4]
20: A[1][0] <-the 1st subarray starts - note the 5 elements before it
24: A[1][1]
28: A[1][2]
32: A[1][3]
36: A[1][4]
40: A[2][0] <-the 2nd subarray starts
44: A[2][1]
48: A[2][2]
52: A[2][3]
56: A[2][4]
60: A[3][0] <-the 3rd subarray starts - the offset 3(5*4) points here
64: A[3][1]
68: A[3][2]
72: A[3][3]
76: A[3][4] <-------- This is what you want
80: A[4][0]
84: A[4][1]
88: A[4][2]
92: A[4][3]
96: A[4][4]
```

So in order to get to element [3,4], you have to skip 3 **complete** subarrays, each of size 5*4 bytes, and then skip 4 more elements in the 4th subarray.

EDIT: that about about the toy example of a 5x5 array of 4 byte values, now on to the specific problem. Note that it's an array of 8 byte longs. So the formula for the offset of element [i][j] in an array of [A][B] is rewritten to:

```
array_base + A*i*8 + j*8
```

which can be rewritten as

```
array_base + 8*(A*i + j)
```

So, by figuring out what happens to index one can recover the *first* dimension of the array.

Now, about the assembly snippet. The formulae were worked out correctly: the offset to the element of Q is `8*(5*j + i)`, the offset to the element of P is `8*(7*i + j)`. Let's note that the general formula for the offset of the element of an `[A][B]` array doesn't involve the value of `B` at all. Also, let's notice that P is declared as `P[M][N]` and Q is declared as `Q[N][M]` - the dimensions are reversed. Ergo, the first dimension of P is 7 and the first dimension of Q is 5. So, N is and M is 7.

The thing to pay attention to, in the snippet above, M and N don't just stand for the "first dimension" and the "second dimension". So using them as placeholders in a general formula would be somewhat misleading.

Comment: What I meant is that since arrays start from 0, 3 means that you are on 4th element of that particular array. To achieve that fourth element, first you have to skip 3 elements. I totally aware of what you said. What I am asking is that, do I miss something?

Comment: Let me draw a picture.

Comment: We are on the same approach. I just mistyped there. Sorry about that. So, what is your opinions about the specific question in the above? What are the M and N values? I am really confused on that *specific* question.

Comment: OBTW, what platform is it on? When targeting x84-64 CPUs, the `long` datatype of C is 4 bytes on Windows and 8 on Linux.

Comment: For this particular example, it is accepted as 8 bytes.

Comment: Did you notice that the order of M and N is different for P and Q?

Comment: Yes I did. For preventing any misunderstandings, this is not a graded homework and I am not faking that I don't understand. P + 8 * 7 * i + 8 * j => You first skip 56*i because 8*i for an element and there are 7. This is why M = 7 and N = 5 (N can not be derived from here, apply the same process for Q then you will get N value).

Comment: I am freaking out, so lost. Please tell me step by step if it is fine for you.

Comment: I'll try. So the problem is: we have two arrays P and Q, both two-dimensional, P with dimensions M and N, Q with dimensions N and M (the other way around). Given a piece of assembly that retrieves an element of P and an element of Q by two indices (provided in RDI and RSI), you need to figure out the values of M and N. Is that understood?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Only problem I have concentrates on the last two lines of assembly (excluding ret).

Comment: By convention, the return value goes into RAX. So the second to last line loads Q[i][j] into RAX, using RDI, which by that time contains the offset within Q *in elements*. It applies the factor of 8 to the offset to account for the size of long. The line after that adds the value of P[i][j] to RAX, similarly using RDX. So the final value of RAX is P[i][j] + Q[i][j], as intended.

Comment: Alright, thank you but the problem I have is that how can you derive P is a matrix with 5 rows and 7 columns or P[M][N] == P[5][7]? Sorry If I took you long.

Comment: The values of M and N are shared between P and Q. We can learn N from the formula for element offset in Q, and we can learn N from the formula for P. Since P is declared as P[N][M], we know both dimensions. I think you are confused between array declaration and array access, since the syntax in C is the same.

Comment: to be more precise, how does [P + 8*(7*i + j)] gives you the information that P has 7 columns?

Comment: Nevermind, we are not gonna end up with happy ending as far as I can see so I do not want to take your time anymore. Thank you so much friend.

Comment: Given a double dimensioned array, we cannot see the size of the upper/first/outer index from an expression that uses the array -- we can only see the lower/second/inner size.  However, since the two arrays swap their dimensions, we can see N from an access to P and M from an access to Q.  The lower/second/inner size is a factor in the address calculation, so if you also know the size of the elements, than that inner array size can be derived by dividing out the element size from the multiplication observed.

Comment: I am assuming the arrays are stored in row, column order - row 0, then row 1, etc. The element access formula uses the row size. The row size of P is the column size in Q and vice versa. The generated code gives us the two row sizes, by flipping them we can learn column sizes. The compiler knows the array dimensions and generates code with that knowledge.

Comment: To answer the last question, I know that because I know how are two dimensional arrays arranged in memory, by C language convention. If in order to get to row i of P one needs to skip 7*i elements, that means that one row in P is 7 elements long. Row size is the same as column count, and vice versa. Ergo, 7 columns in P.