# Knowing the dimension of a matrix in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering

```
int array1[H][J];
int array2[J][H];
void copy_array(int x, int y) {
array2[y][x] = array1[x][y];
}
```

say i have the piece of code above, then i am given this assembly;

```
copy_array:
movslq %edi,%rdi # rdi = x
movslq %esi,%rsi # rsi = y
movq %rsi, %rdx # rdx = y
salq $4, %rdx # rdx = 2^4y=16y
subq %rsi, %rdx # rdx = 16y – y = 15y
addq %rdi, %rdx # rdx = 15y+x
leaq 0(,%rdi,8), %rax # rax = 8x
subq %rdi, %rax # rax = 8x-x = 7x
addq %rsi, %rax # rax = 7x+y
movl array1(,%rax,4), 
movl %eax, array2(,%rdx,4) 
ret
```

How do i know the dimension of the matrix as when i illustrate it i was left with literal x,y equation

Comment: You "know" the dimensions the same way as you should know it in C code: By passing them as arguments to the function.

Comment: You have RAX and RDX (the array indices in `int`-sized chunks) in terms of `x` and `y`. 
 The offsets in C terms are like `H*x + y` for one of them, so you can construct 2 equations in 2 unknowns.  (You don't have to solve for x and y, just H and J).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The matrix *dimensions* aren't args to the function, they're available at compile-time via the declarations.  That's why the scale factors are baked into to shifts / subs / adds in the machine code, not an `imul` by a runtime variable.  The args are the *indices*; the incoming EDI and ESI values.

Comment: Near duplicate of [Reverse engineering and interpreting assembly code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67732896) - different details of the code, but same problem of `[H][J]` and `[J][H]` dimensions.

Comment: We know that `a[i][j]` is accessed using an expression `(i × columnCount + j) * elementSize + a`, right?  So, if you know the factors you know the columnCount for the array.  Since both arrays are accessed,  you know two columnCounts, and here that means you also know the rowCounts.  So, your job is to identify the columnCount values from the assembly code.