# 80286: Which is the fastest way to multiply by 10?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, micro-optimization

To multiply a number by any any multiple of 2, I'll shift it those many times.

Is there any such technique to multiply a number by 10 in less cycles?

Comment: Specifically on 80286, so immediate shifts are available, but `imul reg,reg,10` is slow, and 32-bit addressing modes like `lea ax, [eax + eax*4]` aren't available for cheap `x * 5`?  Do you care about performance of the code on any later or earlier CPUs, in case something that's optimal for 286 isn't optimal elsewhere?  Do you have a link for 80286 instruction timings?

Comment: Shift, add, shift?  `10*x = (4*x + x) * 2 = ((x << 2) + x) << 1`.  This is the same way you do "long multiplication" by hand.

Comment: Yes my old friend, I am currently coding only for 80286 (16-bit)

Comment: @NateEldredge How would the value of x remain persistent while adding it once the bits are shifted?

Comment: You save it in another register.  `mov bx, ax ; shl ax, 2 ; add ax, bx ; shl ax, 1`.

Comment: @NateEldredge:  Yes, I think we're stuck with something like that.  But is `add same,same` faster or slower than `shl reg,1` on 286 for that last step?  It probably doesn't matter what order you do anything in; 286 can't exploit the ILP in `x*2 + x*8`, and I think we need 1 `mov`.  Unless you happened to already have the value in SI|DI and BX|BP, then you could `lea ax, [bx + si]` or something to start with `x*2`

Comment: Will it be more efficient than MUL?

Comment: @ProjectZero: On 286, yes vastly.  The threshold for doing shifts/adds instead of a `mul` by a constant is at least a few set bits even on P5 Pentium; 10 only has 2 set bits.  On modern Nehalem or later, yes better than 1-operand `mul`, but not better than `imul ax, bx, 10`.  (3 cycle latency, 1/clock throughput, 1 uop)

Comment: Could either of you'll please post an answer so that I could accept it?

Comment: I'm not sure how shifts and adds compare, but you can also do it with four adds: `mov bx, ax ; add ax, ax ; add ax, ax ; add ax, bx ; add ax, ax`.

Comment: Without knowing where to find a 286 instruction timing table, I don't know what the fastest version would be so I don't know the answer.  The generic method of breaking a multiply down into shifts and add/sub is well known and wouldn't be new.  (And BTW, I mentioned P5 Pentium earlier because you can see how GCC optimizes multiplies by constants when tuning for it with `gcc -O3 -march=pentium`.  Or even `-march=i386`.  https://godbolt.org/z/qjD-a3.  Oh, you could compile for MIPS to limit GCC to just using shifts and add/sub, not x86 LEA.  Or maybe MPS430 as a 2-operand machine.

Comment: Wow, 80286. It's borderline whether this question should be shifted over to https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 80286 did not have a barrel shifter, that was introduced with the 80386. According to the timing tables in the Microsoft Macro Assembler 5.0 documentation (1987), **SHL** *reg, immed8* takes 5+n cycles, whereas **SHL** *reg,* **1** takes 2 cycles. **ADD** *reg, reg* takes 2 cycles, as does **MOV** *reg, reg*. **IMUL** *reg16, immed* takes 21 cycles. Therefore, the fastest way to multiply by ten would appear to be:

```
           ;       // cycles
shl ax, 1  ; *2    // 2
mov bx, ax ; *2    // 4
shl ax, 1  ; *4    // 6
shl ax, 1  ; *8    // 8
add ax, bx ; *10   // 10
```

or, alternatively:

```
           ;      // cycles
mov bx, ax ; *1   // 2
shl ax, 1  ; *2   // 4
shl ax, 1  ; *4   // 6
add ax, bx ; *5   // 8
shl ax, 1  ; *10  // 10
```

Ten cycles either way.