# How to convert int8 to int16 in avr

Tags: assembly, integer, avr, sign-extension

In my computer science class, we just started working in AVR this week. I am having trouble with the bit manipulation required to convert an 8-bit int to a 16-bit int. For context, I am running the program off an arduino.

This is what I have so far:

```
.global int8ToInt
int8ToInt:
sbrc r24,7
ldi r25,127
cp r25,r24
sbi r25,r25
ret
```

This is just what I have from looking a bit at docs and similar problems on this website, but I do not know where to go from here, or even if this is quite right. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The simplest is to `clr r25; sbrc r24, 7; dec r25`.

Comment: Just those three? Or adding those 3 as lines after the ```sbi r25```?

Comment: Just those. Actually, `mov r25, r24; asr r25, 7` is even simpler.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You can always ask a compiler. gcc seems to do `mov r0, r24; lsl r0; sbc r25,r25`.

Comment: @Jester: Is there no shorter way to get CF set according to the high bit of r24?  Like cmp-immediate?  No probably not, you'd need a reverse-subtract `0x7f - x` - ARM has that, AVR doesn't. Or an `add reg, 0x80` but add writes the register.   (re: `asr r25, 7` - remember that AVR only has shift-by-1.  If that assembles at all, it would be a pseudo-instruction for 7 ASRs, which is horrible :/)

Comment: Note that zero-extension (unsigned) is much easier, just clear the high half.  If you know your `int8` values are always non-negative, you can do that.

Comment: Ah yeah, no multi-bit `ASR`.

Comment: There is `BST` but unfortunately that writes the special T flag not C.

Comment: @Jester there's no barrel shifter in tiny microcontrollers like AVR, so the [AVR can only shift 1 bit at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17908514/995714), there's no `ASR r25, 7`

Comment: check the output from GCC https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Pe1rnf